# Firefox randomly begins to open tabs like crazy

Tags: firefox, php, download, browser-tabs

Sometimes, when I'm browsing a random site, suddenly a 0 byte PHP file will be downloaded out of nowhere and Firefox (3.5.2) will start opening it in multiple tabs really quickly, so that I have to press Ctrl + W (close tab) as fast as I can until all the rogue tabs are closed. This file is frequently named diggthis.php, and some time ago it was a name I can't remember but it was the name of a search engine.

Could this be malware on my computer? Maybe a XSS attempt in the page I'm browsing?

Comment: upgrade to 3.5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much likely malware on your computer. Use nice little proggie malwarebytes antimalware. Then install NoScript plugin to Firefox and you'll be a happier person.

Really - NoScript helps prevent 90+% of malware by effectively disabling entry points. You will need to manually allow scripts on trusted sites, but this thing is worth a few clicks now and then. I mean, it is so effective against malware that I can't find a sane reason why not have it.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Malwarebytes Antimalware - the app can't get enough publicity

Comment: I know about NoScript, and I used it for some time, but I found it too annoying.

Comment: Well, you are not the first to notice it is annoying :) It's a subjective, tho. I rather have clean computer and simply click Temporary allow xyz.abc or Temporary allow everything on this site if I believe the site is trustworthy, than cleaning malware three times a month. :)

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Comment: The antivirus detected some malware. I'll mark this answer as accepted if for a few days the problem doesn't happen again.

Answer (score -1):

If you still has problem with other browsers except Firefox (you might see the malware behaviors like opening tabs in them either), just download and install Hitman Pro from a secure website like cnet, it detects malware and associated files in your registry (type regedit in your start and then control F to find the file).